# Linux console commands in C++ (gcc compiler)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, console

How can I give commands to Linux console (Ubuntu) from my c++ program, and assign a value, which my command tells, to string variable? Please, give me an example, in which program gives simple command "uname -a" to console and writes result.

Sorry for my bad English, I know it very little. I would be very happy, if someone will write his answer in Russian (if it allowed) . I was looking for the answer to my question in Russian resources, but found nothing, you're my last hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you need is `popen`.  You can get information about it by typing `man popen` into your shell; if your Linux distribution runs its Russian translation, it should display the information about it in Russian.

Basically, `popen` just opens a "file" (stream), with which you can work just like with a regular file.  Here's an example of how it could be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *f;
  char stuff[100];
  f = popen("uname -a", "r");
  fgets(stuff, 100, f);
  printf("%s", stuff);
  pclose(f);
}
```

The code above doesn't have any error handling; you should insert the appropriate checks after you read and understand [the complete manual page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) ([rus](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=popen&category=3&russian=0)).

Answer (score 1):

Look for Russian language resources that explain the popen(3) library routine. You will need to use popen to launch the command, then read the pipe to obtain the output.